# OutofMemory issue in Wso2 ESB 4.8 using JSON -eval

Tags: wso2-esb

We are using smooks to transform CSV to XML and then XML to JSON. This is done in sequence in Wso2 esb 4.8.1 using following components

1. Smooks mediator transforms csv to xml
2. Then json-eval transforms xml to json

We have 100000 record in csv the transformation is done parallelly in  50 threads using iterator.

First time when wso2 esb server is started it executes fine. However second run i.e. at break of 5 min. We get following error.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:2694)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:203)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.toString(StringBuffer.java:561)
    at java.io.StringWriter.toString(StringWriter.java:210)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.toString(OMElementImpl.java:996)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.stringValueOf(SynapseXPath.java:321)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorProperty.getEvaluatedExpression(MediatorProperty.java:138)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.setCustomProperties(LogMediator.java:192)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getCustomLogMessage(LogMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.getLogMessage(LogMediator.java:117)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator.mediate(LogMediator.java:97)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.MediatorWorker.run(MediatorWorker.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

We have followed the performance tunning parameter of wso2 esb 4.8.1 
Appreciate if anyone can please let us know if tuning on xpath or smooks or any other parameters/option could help.

Comment: From the stack trace alone we cannot deduce xpath is the reason for the OOM - the memory could have grown due to some other reason and it went OOM during an xPath evaluation is more likely. You should profile the ESB to find out where all the memory is going and consider your JVM memory settings, is it enough for the load you are handling?

Answer (score 0):

We have profiled using jprofiler. Attached snapshot of the same. Our test proved that when we remove json-eval that is used to covert xml to json we do not get memory leak caused due byte[] and char[]. 
I am unable to past the image of jprofiler. 
However evey run of our esb service that has xml to json conversion using json-eval. We see that byte[] and char[] getting buildup in jprofiler. When we change our solution to avoid using json-eval then these object are no longer visible and memory looks pretty good. 
However in our solution we need to convert hug xml to json before the response from service is rendered,  hence using transformation like json-eval is needed .

Ideally we suspect that conversion of huge xml to json using json-eval needs to be fine tuned.

Appreciate if anyone can share any in-sight on same.

Thanks,
Anjana.